# How to align both these elements in same line?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a `textarea` and a  `submit` button.

Before adding `<form>` element it looked like

[image]

Now, after surrounding those two elements with `<form>`, it changed to

[image]

```
<div class="input-group">
     <form>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message"/>
       <span class="input-group-btn" >   
         <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">SEND</button>
       </span>
     </form>
</div>
```

How to get back the previous view with the `<form>` element included?

I am using [angular-bootstrap-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I have a `custom.css` file where I can override the default bootstrap CSS. I tried with ids for form and button, but didn't achieve the exact result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input-group should be inside the form. Like so:

```
<form>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message">
    <span class="input-group-btn">   
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">SEND</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: As simple as it can get. Thank you!